# using parenthesis in SQL

Tags: sql

What's the differences between these SQLs:

```
SELECT *
FROM COURS NATURAL JOIN COMPOSITIONCOURS NATURAL JOIN PARCOURS; 

SELECT *
FROM COURS NATURAL JOIN (COMPOSITIONCOURS C JOIN PARCOURS P ON C.IDPARCOURS = P.IDPARCOURS) ;

SELECT *
FROM (COURS NATURAL JOIN COMPOSITIONCOURS C) JOIN PARCOURS P ON C.IDPARCOURS = P.IDPARCOURS ;
```

They have different results.

Comment: Please provide sample result sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of yours answers! I finally find out that the problem is because of the use of natural JoIn. 
When using natural join, it will join every column with the same name! When I am using NATURAL JOIN for several times , it's possible those columns, which have same names but you don't wants to combine , could be joined automatically!
Here is an example,
Table a (IDa, name,year,IDb)
Table b (IDb, bonjour,salute,IDc)
Table c (IDc, year, merci)
If I wrote like From a Natural Join b Natural c,because IDb and IDc are common names for Table a,b,c.  It seems Ok! But attention please! 
a.year and b.year can also be joined ! That's what we don't want!

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell precisely without a sample result set, but I would imagine its your utilization of natural JOINs which is typically bad practice. Reasons being:

I would avoid using natural joins, because natural joins are:

- Not standard SQL.
- Not informative. You aren't specifying what columns are being joined without referring to the schema.
- Your conditions are vulnerable to schema changes. If there are multiple natural join columns and one such column is removed from a table, the query will still execute, but probably not correctly and this change in behavior will be silent.

Comment: Not standard?  Really?

Comment: `NATURAL JOIN` **is** defined in the SQL standard and thus it is "standard SQL"